# Angular Material Input control

Tags: angular, input, angular-material2

I am trying to implement this input control

```
<div layout-gt-sm="row">
  <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
    <label>First name</label>
    <input ng-model="user.firstName">
  </md-input-container>
</div>
```

I get error:

```
Unexpected directive 'MdInputContainer' imported by the module 'AppMaterialModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
```

This is what AppMaterialModule looks like.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {
    MdToolbarModule,
    MdIconModule,
    MdMenuModule,
    MdButtonModule,
    MdSelectModule,
    MdSnackBarModule,
    MdSnackBar, MdInputContainer, MdInputModule
} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        MdToolbarModule,
        MdButtonModule,
        MdIconModule,
        MdMenuModule,
        MdSelectModule,
        MdSnackBarModule,
        MdInputContainer,
        MdInputModule
    ],
    exports: [
        MdToolbarModule,
        MdButtonModule,
        MdIconModule,
        MdMenuModule,
        MdSelectModule,
        MdSnackBarModule,
        MdInputContainer,
        MdInputModule

    ],
    providers: [
        MdSnackBar
    ]
})
export class AppMaterialModule {}
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried using md-input instead of md-input-container. I get error with that too.

Comment: AFAIK, you should only import **modules**. `MdInputContainer` is a directive that lives in `MdInputModule`... so once you import `MdInputModule` you'll be able to use this directive or any other directive/component that is declared by this module. Also it's `[(ngModel)]`, not `ng-model` (don't forget to import `FormsModule` from `@angular/forms`).

Comment: I have made those changes, but now I get the error:'md-input-container' is not a known element:
1. If 'md-input-container' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'md-input-container' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you use `mdInput` for in the input tag, as in

```
<md-input-container>
   <input mdInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.firstName" ...>
</md-input-container>
```

(as already noted it is `[(ngModel)]`, not `ng-model`)